# Compiling android-7.0.0_r13: "ninja: error: unknown target 'otapackage'"

Tags: android, android-source

I'm wanting to learn how to build my own Nexus 6P ROM and I've been trying to compile Nougat for my 6P to no avail. I've posted on XDA and no one's willing to help me.  I feel like I'm never going to learn because no one will help me figure out what I'm doing wrong. :(  My build keeps erroring out with:

```
Starting build with ninja
ninja: Entering directory `.'
ninja: error: unknown target 'otapackage'
build/core/ninja.mk:148: recipe for target 'ninja_wrapper' failed
make: *** [ninja_wrapper] Error 1

#### make failed to build some targets (48 seconds) ####
```

I can't find any information on the google machine regarding this error or how to troubleshoot it.

My build environment consists of Builduntu v2 running in a VirtualBox VM w/15.5GB of RAM allocated to the VM.

I've been following the guide from https://source.android.com/source/building.html.  I downloaded source via:

```
repo init -u https://android.googlesource.com/platform/manifest -b android-7.0.0_r13
repo sync
```

And things sync'd fine.  Now I'm trying to build.  I did "make clobber", "source build/envsetup.sh", and "lunch aosp_angler-userdebug" and those all ran fine.  But "make otapackage -j8" fails with the error from above.  I've been stuck on this for 2 days and can't find any answers.  Please help me, I'm growing frustrated with this and want to give up.

Answer (score -1):

recovery_fstab is NULL? in build/core/Makefile file.